# Wrong type of iterator used

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a map as part of my HW assignment. The map should support two types of iterators:

- iterator - allows changing the map.
- constant_iterator - doesn't allow changing the map.

I have the following methods:

```
Map::const_iterator begin() const;
Map::const_iterator end() const;
Map::iterator begin();
Map::iterator end();
```

However when I test my implementation with the following code:

```
for(Map<std::string,int>::const_iterator it = msi.begin(); it != msi.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following problem:

```
map_test.cpp:49:43: error: no viable conversion from 'Map<basic_string<char>, int>::iterator' to 'Map<std::string, int>::const_iterator'
        for(Map<std::string,int>::const_iterator it = msi.begin(); it != msi.end(); ++it) {
                                                 ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~
./map_new.h:57:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Map<basic_string<char>, int>::iterator' to 'const
      Map<basic_string<char>, int>::const_iterator &' for 1st argument
                const_iterator(const Map<KeyType, DataType>::const_iterator& sIterator): 
                ^
```

Which means that the compiler selects the wrong begin/end methods.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By providing an implicit conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator`. You can do this by giving `const_iterator` a constructor that takes an `iterator`, or by providing `iterator` with a `const_iterator` conversion operator.

This approach is used in the standard library when you do this kind of thing:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
```

In C++11, you have methods that return `const_iterators` directly, even for non-const instances. But these need a different name, because you cannot overload by return type:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.cbegin();
```

Comment: But this will only bypass the problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Doppelganger No, it should solve the problem. This is what happens in standard library containers.

Comment: It indeed solves the problem, thanks. [I was sure more elegant solution exists]

Answer (score 2):

You may also create `cbegin()` and `cend()` member functions that will return const iterators.

Comment: you forgot to add that cbegin/cend arrived with c++11 standard and will not work with early compilers.

Comment: TS implements his own Map class, so he may pick any name he likes

Comment: @Sergey It doesn't matter since these functions will be defined at custom class

Answer (score 2):

You have several options to avoid this problem.

1. Use iterator instead of const_iterator in "for" loop
2. Define object like the following:

   ```
   const Map<string, int> msi;
   ```
3. Define operator at your iterator class to convert Map::const_iterator into Map::iterator